# How to make both commands can puts in to discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Funny happen, when I added `@bot.command()` (this code is used to send an image when it detects a command, it will send an image in discord.py, it can work).
But if I added `@bot.event()` (this code is used for keyword search, if it searches any keywords, it will send a message to reply) in discord.py together, it can't work.
That's means I can't put that two functions in discord.py together, how can I solve it?
Here is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def Send a photo(ctx):
    await ctx.send('image_1')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    keyword = ['morning','goodbye']
    for key in keyword:
        if key in msg.content and key == keyword[0] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
            break 
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[1] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_goodbye = random.choice(jdata['GOODBYE'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_goodbye)
            break
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way to do this... Why didn't you just do something without a for-loop like: `if keyword[0] in msg.content ...:`

Answer (score 1):

#### The faq page of the documentation mentions how to fix this issue: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Essentially, overriding the default provided on_message doesn't allow any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(msg) line at the end of your on_message. So just use:

```py
async def on_message(msg):
    keyword = ['morning','goodbye']
    for key in keyword:
        if key in msg.content and key == keyword[0] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
            break 
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[1] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_goodbye = random.choice(jdata['GOODBYE'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_goodbye)
            break
    bot.process_commands(msg)
```

By the way, the code

```py
keyword = ['morning','goodbye']
    for key in keyword:
        if key in msg.content and key == keyword[0] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
            break 
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[1] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_goodbye = random.choice(jdata['GOODBYE'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_goodbye)
            break
```

can be shortened to

```py
if "morning" in msg.content:
    random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
    await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
elif "goodbye" in msg.content:
    random_goodbye = random.choice(jdata['GOODBYE'])
    await msg.channel.send(random_goodbye)
```